# Why do larger breakpoints collapse before smaller breakpoints?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Consider these two slightly different bits of code using bootstrap:

a)

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:blue;">First</div>
   <div class="col-lg-8" style="background-color:red;">Second</div>
</div>
```

b)

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:blue;">First</div>
   <div class="col-xs-8" style="background-color:red;">Second</div>
</div>
```

As you drag the side of your browser and reduce the width, the second code will behave differently than the first.

Somehow the `col-lg-*` divs will be separated into two lines sooner (at higher browser width) than the `col-xs-*` divs.

I read the CSS file provided by Bootstrap and my first idea was that the `col-lg-*` classes have a higher min-width property. Sadly, however, I couldn't find anything besides identical width, margin, and padding values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the framework is built to be mobile first. Since you do not specify the smaller breakpoints with your first bit of code, they are assumed to be 12 columns.

For example, these two lines of code are identical:

```
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
```

is the same as:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4"></div>
```

This is why the divs are breaking down sooner. It's because they are hitting the next-smallest breakpoint.

Comment: Yeah I see your point. I didn't check attentively enough the @media rules. So if I go below 1200px screen width simply the .col-lg-* classes are undefined and same goes for the other classes too with the right width values.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**@Media** is used for mobile development.

Min-Width isn't necessarily just for mobile development either, as you said; it is a constraint that stops segments from collapsing on themselves as you resize your browser page - used for consistency across screen resolutions.

And if you look at both div classes, `col-lg` `col-xs`

```
xs (phones), sm (tablets), md (desktops), and lg (larger desktops)
```

So, naturally - the larger div will be re-sized before the smaller one.
These values are definitely in one of the bootstrap files, you just need to keep looking - or - if you're using a pre-made template they may be located within the custom CSS File instead, which over-rides the default Bootstrap.css

Comment: Thank you for your time and answere!